# finding constantness of a term

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages

Let $S$ be a multisorted algebraic [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28logic%29) with function symbols $f_0, f_1, \ldots$. For every $i$, I partially know “constantness” of $f_i$. (I have no precise definition of constantness yet.) Examples:

- Let $\cdot$ denote multiplication of numbers. If $x_0=0$, then $x_0\cdot x_1$ is constant.
- Conditional operation. If $x_0=0$ and $x_2$ is constant, then  $\operatorname{if}x_0\operatorname{then}x_1\operatorname{else}x_2$ is constant.

I need to find a strongest constantness judgement for any term over $S$ given constantness of its variables. Is there an established way of reasoning about constantness?

A purpose is that every term in $S$ defines a function from program states to a pixel on a screen. Variables of the term are components of a state, i.e. the set of states is a Cartesian product. For every pixel $p$, if its term is found to be non-constant then I need to redraw $p$.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the compiler literature for some ideas.  What you're describing is akin to a well-known compiler optimization (virtually any modern compiler worth its salt will do it) called constant folding.  Of course, constant folding goes further in not just identifying constant expressions, but replacing them by their value.

In particular, compilers use a dataflow analysis to identify such constant expressions.  Any good compiler textbook will discuss this.

Comment: This sounds promising, I am going to look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making a very precise analysis at the level of pixels, which is surely undecidable, you could design a program analysis that computes bounding boxes of either the set of pixels that *may* have changed or the set of pixels that *definitely* have not been changed. Then the given set of boxes (or their complement) are the ones that need to be redrawn.

There might be some work in **[abstract interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation)** that deals with this topic, but a quick google search didn't reveal anything.

Comment: I already do what you are suggesting. :) The phrase “may have changed” is neither precise nor formal, and the best way to formalize it I found is “constancy” (former “constantness”) (my English still needs improvement). $\text{“may have changed”}\leftrightarrow\lnot\text{“constant”}$. An output judgement/proposition can be interpreted in the Boolean algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. There is no difference whether we consider individual pixels or sets. So I dropped these considerations.

Comment: BTW, the Boolean algebra of boxes (2D intervals) is also interesting though secondary task.

Comment: Most static analyses are imprecise. They ask _may_ or _must_ questions, which would translate to "this pixel may have changed" or "this pixel must have changed", respectively. The point is that you can calculate an approximation of what has changed. There's plenty of formal work that addresses this topic.

Comment: By “imprecise” I mean “has no formal definition.” Imprecise definitions do not belong to mathematics. And to cstheory.stackexchange.com. :)

Comment: You are dismissing whole areas of computer science. Here's a paper on may and must testing: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/78751/smash.pdf. There are plenty of others like it. All I'm suggesting is that you can apply these formal approaches to the problem you propose, because you are unlikely to find a precise and decidable algorithm to do what you want.

Comment: “You are dismissing whole areas of computer science.” No.

Comment: What I mean to say is that there are whole theories for dealing with the notion of "may have changed", so it is inaccurate to say that it is imprecise and does not belong in mathematics and on cstheory.stackexchange.com. Abstract interpretation is one unifying framework for such theories.